# java forgot password implementation library

Tags: java, passwords, forgot-password, email-verification

We have a web app with a Java backend.
Currently we have a simple username / password login/sign-up page (on sign-up you also enter an email).

We want to implement a 'forgot password' functionality, and on sign-up an email verification functionality.

Should I implement it myself, or are there Java packages/SDKs which do that for me?

(I think there must be - because it is a very common functionality - but I didn't find any)

Comment: did you made login manually?

Comment: yes. but i'm open to change it.

Comment: Do not implement security (including user management) on your own. Use a library, e.g. take a look at [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).